# When adding custom fonts to jsPDF, some do not appear to work if the compression option is set to true

Tags: jspdf

I recently discovered jsPDF new compression option. I've also been playing around with adding custom fonts that support foreign characters besides English when generating a PDF. Whenever I use the compression option and set it to true, some of the custom fonts do not appear to work within the PDF. Specifically Simplified Chinese, Korean and Japanese. Of course, I could just not use the compression option, but it's nice to have a compressed PDF.

view code: [here](https://github.com/DmanCoder/font-test-with-jsPDF/blob/master/src/App.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

// arial-unicode-ms.ttf font converted to base64 
import { base64Str } from './base64';

function App() {
  const genPDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF({
      compress: true,
      orientation: 'p',
      unit: 'px',
      format: 'a4'
    });

    // ADDING FONT FILE
    doc.addFileToVFS('unicodeMS.ttf', base64Str);
    doc.addFont('unicodeMS.ttf', 'unicodeMS', 'normal');
    doc.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);
    doc.setFillColor(135, 124,45,0);

    console.log(doc.getFontList());
    console.log(base64Str);

    doc.setFont('unicodeMS');

    const x = 30,
      y = 30;

    doc.text('Vietnamese: Chào thế giới', x, y);
    doc.text('Chinese: 你好，世界', x, y+15);
    doc.text('Arabic: مرحبا بالعالم', x, y+30);
    doc.text('Hebrew: שלום עולם', x, y+45);
    doc.text('Japanese: こんにちは世界', x, y+60);
    doc.text('English: Hello world', x, y+75);
    doc.text('Korean: 안녕하세요 세계', x, y+90);

    window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={genPDF}>test pdf gen</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Denis - I'm not able to provide an answer, but I'd recommend including the code you're currently using to define your compression options in your post, rather than just providing a link. Good luck!

Comment: @MattSaunders Thanks for the heads up. Hope someone can provide a solution.